# Is it possible to manually sync reminders with iCloud whenever you want?

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization, reminders

I regularly seem to have problems with my reminders not syncing in a timely manner. I am using the Reminders app on my iMac (OS X 10.11.6).

Is there some way for me to manually sync my reminders with iCloud?

I’m thinking something like the option to ‘get mail’ in the Mail app that you can click on to manually get your mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only by revealing the Debug menu in Reminders. To do this:

1. Launch the Terminal app (usually found in the Applications > Utilities folder)
2. Enter the following command (or just copy and paste it):

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.reminders RemindersDebugMenu -boolean true
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>
4. Now launch your Reminders app (or, if it was already open, quit it and launch it again)

Now you can go to Debug > Refresh (or just press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) to refresh your Reminders with iCloud.

**NOTES:**

- If the above process doesn’t reveal the Debug menu, then quit the Reminders app and start again at Step 2.
- If you ever want to hide the Debug menu, then follow the same process but at Step 2 enter the following command instead:

  ```
  defaults delete com.apple.reminders RemindersDebugMenu
  ```

Comment: How'd you find out about this?

Comment: Gosh, I couldn't tell you how I originally found out about this. However, this isn't anything new (I remember doing this in Yosemite) and many of Apple's apps have hidden Debug menus that can be enabled via terminal commands. As for the *refresh* option, it's just something I noticed when I first enabled this menu in Reminders.

Comment: Brings up the menu, but seems to do nothing at all. Using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 & iOS 12.1.3